# EntityFramework: can I force many-to-many (partial-key association) to a one-to-many relation by adding a fixed value for the missing key part?

Tags: c#-4.0, many-to-many, entity-framework-5, relationship, ef-database-first

I'm working with a database that I can't change, and I'm working with EF database-first...

I've got some tables with a many-to-many relation to a 'shared' table.
The relation based on the keys is many-to-many, but it's actually zero-or-one-to-many relation made unique by a fixed value in the shared table.

Example:

Table1; field:code, ...

Table2; field:code, ...

SharedTable; key1:code, key2:tablename, ...

If I use the EF designer to model this, I can only use the Table1:code to SharedTable:key1 for the assiociation, resulting in a many-to-many relation which is not allowed.

Is there any way to 'model' these associations to include a fixed value for SharedTable:key2, or force many-to-many relations to be allowed, so I could add the 'where key2=tablename' and ' manually for example?

Of course I could always resort to dropping the associations and joining manually...

Comment: ...??? No code, no example, no picture, ... So how can we help...?!